# How to get the difference between two IPv6 address in C, consedering all 128 bits?

Tags: c, networking, ipv6

I am trying to get the difference between 2 IPv6 address. eg. Given an address range from min_v6_address to max_v6_address. I need 
"uint32 offset = max_v6_address - min_v6_address" 
to get the total number of IP's between them in C language.

Thanks.

Comment: So what is the problem? BTW, why do you think the offset will fit into 32 bits?

Comment: "_...get the total number of IP's..._" There are only two current IPs: IPv4 and IPv6. I think you mean IP addresses.

Comment: That's normally nothing you should get from the addresses, but the prefix-size. In addition to @EugeneSh. s comment: `*uint32 offset` is not a valid declaration. There is no type `uint32` in the standard and the notation is wrong, too. In case you mean `uint32_t *offset`: why do you think IP addresses are pointers?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/189912